# CKEditor внутри jquery.Arcticmodal

Tags: django, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Здравствуйте, проблема такова. Есть Django проект, нужно поле CKEditor'а внутри модального окна arcticmodal.
Вне окна проблем никаких нет, все работает,  если редактор находится в модальном окне, то ни на что не реагирует, не появляется курсов ввода, не набирается текст.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам поможет: [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637455/how-to-use-ckeditor-in-a-bootstrap-modal) или [здесь](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Issue-with-Twitter-Bootstrap)